# What is an antiunitary operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematics

What is an [antiunitary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator)? In field theory one can define a time reversal operator $T$ such that $T^{-1} \phi (x) T = \phi (\mathcal T x)$. It is then proved that $T$ must be [antiunitary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator): $T^{-1} i  T = -i$.

How is this equation to be understood? If $i$ is just the unit complex number, why don't we have $T^{-1} i  T = i T^{-1} T$ which is just the identity times $i$?

Comment: $T$ is an _antilinear_ (or _conjugate-linear_) map, cf.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map

Comment: One can think of $i$ as a multiplication operator that commutes with complex linear operators but anticommutes with complex anti-linear operators. Hence, $Ti+iT=0$. One *can* think of $i$ as a 2-by-2 matrix, if one wants to be very concrete.

Comment: Hey, Unitarians are awesome! At least, all the other operators think so, which is why they don't talk to $T$ anymore ;-) I fixed the question to read "antiunitary".

Comment: @Qmechanic is anti-unitary the same as anti-linear?

Comment: $\uparrow $ No.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I correctly understood your misunderstanding, the answer is: operator is not always a matrix. Technically, action of time inversion operator contains complex conjugation. 
E.g., in spin up/spin down basis it is written as $-i\sigma_y\mathcal{K}$, where $\mathcal{K}$ is complex conjugation.

Comment: I think that has been the source of my misunderstanding. I have considered T to be a matrix commutating with $i$. But it seems it is a more generic kind of operator.

Answer (score 10):

As Qmechanic noted, $T$ is *antilinear* (this is part of the definition of being antiunitary).  Of course, $T^{-1}$ must be antilinear as well because $T$ is.  Thus, for any vector in this Hilbert space $v$, $T^{-1}(iv)=-iT^{-1}(v)$.  The $i$ pops out as a $-i$.  Applying this to your equation, we easily have that
$$
T^{-1}iT=-iT^{-1}T=-i.
$$

Comment: It is unfortunately the case that many sources refer to antiunitary operators as just "operators" (e.g., the "CPT operator") even though in almost all other contexts "operator" implies linearity rather than antilinearity.

Answer (score -3):

I think that just wrong (the wikipedia thing)

1. $i \in \mathbb C$ so how can an operator act on a scalar?
2. Even if it was right, one knows that $T = T^\dagger = T^{-1} = -T^*$. So take what you read

$$TiT^{-1} = -i$$

and now treat $i$ as an scalar (what is! not a pseudo-!) and it turns out

$$Ti(-T)^* = -T^2 i = -i \Rightarrow T^2 = 1$$

that is what we know about $T$ so it should be wrong that thingy of Wikipedia... ;).

The only real explanation could be a phase, not that $i$ changes it sign when you tossed it with $T$.

Comment: What's wrong with my argument/calculation?

Comment: The argument is on a deeper level: $T$ isn't a linear operator, so most of what you've written above doesn't work. You need to go back to Wigner's theorem: a symmetry can either act on your Hilbert space as some unitary operator (the normal case), *or* as an antiunitary operator $U$ such that $(U \Phi, U \Psi) = (\Phi, \Psi)^*$ (i.e. which flips the complex inner product on your space). If this is the case, $U$ is necessarily antilinear, i.e. $U(a \Psi + b \Phi) = a^* U \Psi + b^* U \Phi$.