# Hermitian conjugate of an antiunitary transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, hilbert-space

In quantum mechanics, one often considers symmetry transformations which are defined in terms of operators which do not change the norm of states in the Hilbert space.
For the [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem#Symmetry_transformations), this symmetry operators are either unitary operators or [antiunitary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator), which generally have the form
$
A=U K
$
where $K$ is complex conjugation and $U$ a unitary operator.
Examples of antiunitary operators describe the time-reversal, the particle-hole symmetry, and the chiral symmetry.

Now let us take a generic Hamiltonian $H$. One can define a unitary transformation as
$
H\rightarrow U H U^\dagger
$.
How one defines an antiunitary transformation instead? Formally, I would write
$$
H\rightarrow A H A^\dagger=U K H (U K)^\dagger=U K H K^\dagger U^\dagger=U H^* U^\dagger
$$
The questions are:

1) Is this definition of antiunitary transformation correct?

2) What is the hermitian conjugate of an antiunitary operator? 
Is it correct to write $(U K)^\dagger=K^\dagger U^\dagger$ or is it $(U K)^\dagger=K U^\dagger$ instead?

I apologize for the multiple questions, but I think they are all related to the meaning of the complex conjugation operator $K$ and its hermitian conjugate $K^\dagger$. I already posted this question to the Mathematics StackExchange but I've been completely misunderstood there...

Comment: Someone should explain to me why I got a downvote for this question in only 10 seconds...

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16193/

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45227/2451

Comment: well, almost a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

For an antilinear operator, as the antiunitaries and the complex conjugation, the definition of adjoint is changed: $$\langle U^{a*}\psi,\phi\rangle=\overline{\langle \psi,U\phi\rangle}$$
where $a*$ stands for anti-adjoint. It is therefore easy to see that the anti-adjoint of $K$ is $K$ itself (and in general the anti-adjoint of an anti-unitary is anti-unitary and satisfies $U^{a*}U=I$).